# How to find certain characters in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to find certain characters in it.

```
playerdeck = ['Ten of Clubs', 'Six of Diamonds', 'Five of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'Five of Diamonds', 'Queen of Clubs', 'Seven of Diamonds']
```

I've tried using this code and it doesn't work:

```
if "Ten" in playerdeck[0:6]:
    print("y")
```

Comment: You need a loop that checks if 'Ten' is in any of the list items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
playerdeck = ['Ten of Clubs', 'Six of Diamonds', 'Five of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'Five of Diamonds', 'Queen of Clubs', 'Seven of Diamonds'] 

s="Ten"
for i in playerdeck:
      if s in i:
           print(i)
           print("Found")
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @johndoe ; Just check the green Tick ​​mark for the answer. (:

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
playerdeck = ['Ten of Clubs','Six of Diamonds','Five of Hearts', \
 'Jack of Spades','Five of Diamonds','Queen of Clubs','Seven of Diamonds']
for i,item in enumerate(playerdeck):
    if 'Ten' in item:
        print('Yes:',i,item)
```

results

```
Yes: 0 Ten of Clubs
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use :

```
>>> [card for card in playerdeck if 'Ten' in card]
['Ten of Clubs']
```

or if you just want to know if there's a Ten in the deck :

```
>>> any(card for card in playerdeck if 'Ten' in card)
True
```